# What is the meaning of "Et t'oublies la carapace qu'elle a de méchant loup"?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, registre-familier

This is part of a song lyric. I can translate literally, but the familier in much of it has evaded me. Here are more lyrics for context:

> Tu lui dis des mots doux forcément elle y prend goût
>   Et t'oublies la carapace qu'elle a de méchant loup
>   Oui je sais tes pensées naviguent dans les siennes
>   Elle était ton hôte, ton armure et puis ta reine
>   Là c'est ton gars qui t'parle, essaie d'faire le bon choix
>   Efface moi ce voile qui tétanise tout tes pas

Comment: Just a guess, but the only way that I can make sense of it is to interpret "oublier" in its "exclure" sense, which in turn can mean "rejeter quelque chose [comme impossible]."  With this "exclure/rejeter" sense of "oublier" in mind, it could mean "And you reject/don't fall for/see through her tough exterior."  (Regardless, I think the correct conjugation of "naviquer" in the line following the one in question would be "[tes pensées] NAVIGUE**NT**.)

Comment: I have fixed a few spelling issues, including the one stated in @PapaPoule's comment. I'm still unsure about "elle était ton hôte", maybe he is saying *elle était ton autre*. In any case, despite being the way it is written everywhere I looked, I can't see how *elle était ton hotte* would work, unless I'm missing a slang meaning.

Comment: Papa Poule -- your answer makes the most sense contextually. It also works with what I perceive to be the sentiment of the song., "À bout de souffle" by Noah Lunsi. I believe the writer may be Haitian or some other nationality and , therefore, some of these expressions could be patois.  Thank you and jilliagre for your thoughts.

Comment: I meant to add: "Elle était ton hotte" pas "hôte" is what shows in the lyric...I guess that either of them could work -- she was your hood/host; your armor and then your queen

Comment: Noah Lunsi is from [Sevran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sevran) (Paris suburb) and has CDR roots. He speaks no *patois* but regular *banlieues* French and likely Lingala (Congo) without any connection with creole from Haiti. I have never heard *hotte* used as a masculine word and even less to mean *capuche*. ***Une** hotte* is something you find in a kitchen or on Santa Klaus' back, not on the top of a head. In any case, don't take the lyrics spelling at face value, there are several obvious typos.

Comment: For example the You tube video writes *Oui je sais tes **penser navigue** dans les siennes*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be slightly rephrased that way:

> Et tu oublies la carapace de méchant loup qu'elle a.

i.e.

and you forget (you no more see) the "bad wolf shell" she has, another variant of the theme "*L'amour rend aveugle*".